# Node Js Server starting but after executed another files

Tags: node.js

I have a app.js file where server start script is locating.

Second file is user.js where I'm just consoling some values.

The problem is, when I'm starting the server the second file content is showing first then server has start?

Comment: share your code

Comment: I would assume you're requiring `user.js` in `app.js` that causes the code to run.